# Code binary categorical (participates: yes/no) as a continuous variable (proportion of cells within participating country) in linear regression model?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, binomial-distribution, continuous-data

I have a question regarding the coding of variables in r for linear regression models:

I did regression analyses to find out the relative importance of 12 variables in predicting different continuous response variables. I want to use different types of linear regression models (OLS, GLMs with binomial distribution, simultaneous autoregressive models).

All predictor variables are continuous, except for one which describes whether or not a country is participating in an international programme. It is essentially a factor with binary coding (country participates: 1/0).

I ran the models at different spatial resolutions (i.e. differently sized grid cells). Because the coarser grids have quite a few cells that overlay with participating an non-participating countries, instead of coding the variable as binary, I calculated the proportion of every grid cell that lies within a participating country.

I arcsine-square-root-transformed the resulting values (between zero and one) and treated them as continuous in my regression models. I would now interpret them as the degree to which a grid cell is participating.

The problem is that while the scatterplots look OK at coarse resolutions, at fine resolutions only a small proportion of grid cells really lies at the boarders between countries, so the vast majority of grid cells are still coded as zeros and ones. Accordingly, the scatterplot looks quite awkward.

Can anyone explain to me which (if any) assumptions I violate for OLS, binomial GLM, SAR, or in general? And of course whether it is a major problem or whether I can still get away with it (or would reviewers tear me apart) ?

I've already run all my models and it took quite some time, so I'd be a bit hesitant to redo everything if that's not absolutely necessary.

Thanks a lot for your help!! 
Carsten

Comment: If, as seems to be the case, you're talking about constructing an independent (predictor-, $x$-) variable, there are no assumptions you need to satisfy for OLS or GLMs. Your question "or in general" is unanswerable. I'm not sure what you mean by "SAR"; seasonal autoregression? something else? As for what reviewers might say, one could only speculate as to what your reviewers *might* come up with. It tends to be a bit of a mixed bag at the best of times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By SAR I mean "simultaneous autoregressive model", which is a type of linear regression model that accounts for spatial autocorrelation in the model residuals. Is there not something like an assumption that a continuous predictor variable is actually genuinely continuous?

Comment: But there's no assumption in OLS or GLMs that a predictor should be continuous; it is what it is and you condition on the observed values. If it were observed with error, that might be an issue; discreteness shouldn't be.

Comment: And should I worry about the scatterplot? Right now there are two vertical bars full of data points at zero and one and just a few data points in between. The regression line seems somewhat lost in that plot. Should I maybe instead report a boxplot based only on the datapoints that are either fully within or without a participating country even though I used intermediate values in the regression models?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't think the scatterplot is very informative? (Does it look something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/wPjf2V4.png)?) As for what you should do instead, if you find a boxplot more informative, you could certainly do that, but there are [other possibilities](http://i.imgur.com/raBRe66.png) that may work well.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much how it looks. But I really like your second approach of visualizing it, thank you!